# how to add NSArray to a UIButton(Property)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

Im working on a xcode5 development for iPad where I needed a custom button type with custom properties, so I added a custom class like so...

CarouselButton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIButton(Property)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *typeOfContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pdfDocumentName;

@end
```

CarouselButton.m

```
#import "CarouselButton.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIButton(Property)

static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_1;
static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_2;

@dynamic typeOfContent;
@dynamic pdfDocumentName;

-(void)setTypeOfContent:(NSObject *)typeOfContent{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_1, typeOfContent, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)typeOfContent{
    return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_1);
}

-(void)setPdfDocumentName:(NSObject *)pdfDocumentName{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_2, pdfDocumentName, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)pdfDocumentName{
    return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_2);
}

@end
```

and the way to fill and call those properties for manipulation:

```
#import "CarouselButton.h"


UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
button          = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.typeOfContent    = [[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"typeOfContent"];
button.pdfDocumentName  = [[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"pdfDocumentName"];
```

---

this works fine, now I can store any info NSString type
but I want to store a NSArray type, so I did this:

CarouselButton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIButton(Property)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *typeOfContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pdfDocumentName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *viewControllerParameters;

@end
```

CarouselButton.m

```
#import "CarouselButton.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIButton(Property)

static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_1;
static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_2;
static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_3;

@dynamic typeOfContent;
@dynamic pdfDocumentName;
@dynamic viewControllerParameters;

-(void)setTypeOfContent:(NSObject *)typeOfContent{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_1, typeOfContent, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)typeOfContent{
    return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_1);
}

-(void)setPdfDocumentName:(NSObject *)pdfDocumentName{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_2, pdfDocumentName, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)pdfDocumentName{
    return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_2);
}

-(void)setviewControllerParameters:(NSObject *)viewControllerParameters{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_3, viewControllerParameters, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)viewControllerParameters{
    return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_3);
}

@end
```

And I use it this way:

```
#import "CarouselButton.h"


UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
button          = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.typeOfContent    = [[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"typeOfContent"];
button.pdfDocumentName  = [[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"pdfDocumentName"];
button.viewControllerParameters = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"viewControllerParameters"]];
```

but I get this error:

> 2014-04-08 18:36:37.320 [10222:60b] -[UIButton
>   setViewControllerParameters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x16591420 2014-04-08 18:36:37.323 eSelect[10222:60b] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIButton setViewControllerParameters:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x16591420'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x308f8f03 0x3b4e2ce7 0x308fc837 0x308fb12f 0x3084a0d8 0xeaa7d 0x110b0f 0x1111d9 0x10f6d3 0x1103c1
>   0x10a43d 0xe97af 0x3312ca53 0x331d730d 0x331d7223 0x331d6801
>   0x331d6529 0x331d6299 0x331d6231 0x33128305 0x32da431b 0x32d9fb3f
>   0x32dceb4d 0x331a489f 0x331a2ea9 0x331a20e7 0x331a206f 0x331a2007
>   0x3319a681 0x3312e697 0x331a1d59 0x331a1829 0x33133615 0x3319982b
>   0x12220b 0x11a09d 0x332467f3 0x332f8cb3 0x331a7e09 0x33120b57
>   0x308c4031 0x308c19bf 0x308c1d0b 0x3082c7a9 0x3082c58b 0x357736d3
>   0x3318b891 0x120361 0x3b9e0ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: You need `setViewControllerParameters`. Your implementation is `setviewControllerParameters`, note the lowercase `v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)setviewControllerParameters:(NSObject *)viewControllerParameters{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY_3, viewControllerParameters, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

In the above setter method change the 'v' to a capital 'V'.

E.g.
`setViewControllerParameters:` not `setviewControllerParameters:`

Comment: @Jesus, no problem. Good thing it was an easy fix!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want every button in your application to have these properties, you should be subclassing `UIButton` into a CarouselButton class rather than creating a 'Property' category on `UIButton`.

All those contortions about AssociatedObjects are really only for categories, not necessary for subclasses.  You don't need any of that code inside your implementation; default setters and getters are created automatically for you by the `@property (nonatomic, retain)`

CarouselButton.h

```
@interface CarouselButton: UIButton

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *typeOfContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pdfDocumentName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *viewControllerParameters;

@end
```

CarouselButton.m

```
#import "CarouselButton.h"

@implementation CarouselButton

@end
```

And use it this way:

```
#import "CarouselButton.h"

CarouselButtton *button = [CarouselButtton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.typeOfContent    = [[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"typeOfContent"];
button.pdfDocumentName  = [[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"pdfDocumentName"];
button.viewControllerParameters = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[itemsCarouselTop objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"viewControllerParameters"]];
```